# Regex to stop processing after word is found

Tags: java, regex

I have a number of strings that have the following format:

> Sent to abc xxx zzzz address more words here

or

> Sent to aaaaa gggggg dddddddddd mailbox more words here

I would like to extract a substring that starts after "Sent to " and stops after "address" or "mailbox". For example, in first case the substring would be as so: "abc xxx zzzz address" and in second case, it would be: "aaaaa gggggg dddddddddd mailbox".

The following expression is not working for me. It includes the "Sent to" and it continues till the end of string. I'd appreciate your feedback.

```
[Sent to ].*[address|mailbox])
```

Comment: Use `[Sent to ].*?[address|mailbox])` ... make the dot _lazy_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are pretty close, except instead of character class `[...]` you should use non-capturing groups `(?:...)` or [lookaheads/lookbehinds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?:Sent to )(.*?)(?:address|mailbox)
```

or

```
(?<=Sent to )(.*?)(?=(address|mailbox))
```

Note the reluctant quantifier `*?` after the dot. It ensures that the capturing ends without grabbing too much input, which would happen with a "greedy" asterisk `*` (i.e. with no question mark).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The second expression did the trick.  So is it right to say that ?<=xyz means don't include xyz and ?= means until after?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(?:Sent to )(.*? words|mailbox)
```

The match will include "Sent to". But the captured group will only include the substring represented by (.*? words|mailbox)